# Adding an opacity on the clip-path with HTML and CSS

Tags: html, css, vue.js

I would like to add an opacity on the clip-path/clip (the area covered by the clip path) like the picture shown below.

[image: Result]

Below is my code for the same

```css
.item--clip .demo {
  width: 200px;
  height: 250px;
}

.item--clip .has-mask {
  position: absolute;
  clip: rect(10px, 190px, 190px, 10px);
}


/* Common ------------------------------------------- */

.item {
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 2em;
  padding-bottom: 2em;
  padding-right: 3em;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #DDD;
  /* counter-increment: mylist; */
}

.item::before {
  /* // content: counter(mylist); */
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  font: 2rem/1 Georgia, serif;
  color: #EEE;
}

.item::after {
  content: '';
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}

.demo {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 30px;
}

.demo::before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -2;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: .7s;
}

.text {
  padding-left: 230px;
}

.item:hover ::before {
  opacity: .4;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="item item--clip">
    <div class="demo">
      <img src="https://img-fotki.yandex.ru/get/5607/5091629.6b/0_612e6_b9039c0d_M.jpg" alt="" class="has-mask" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the purpose of mask:

```css
img {
  width: 200px;
  height: 250px;
  -webkit-mask:
    /*                        X    Y   / wwidth height */
    linear-gradient(#000 0 0) 10px 10px/170px 170px, /* control the clipped part here*/
    linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,0.4) 0 0); /* control the opacity here */
  -webkit-mask-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://img-fotki.yandex.ru/get/5607/5091629.6b/0_612e6_b9039c0d_M.jpg" />
```

Comment: Thanks! I guess this is the right solution :), it would also be great if you can explain the numbers inside thosu linear-gradient. :D

Comment: @Tsokoloy there is no complex logic inside the gradient, the first one need an opaque color and the second one need a transparent color, that's it. It can be any color

Answer (score -2):

Try using the "opacity" command:

```
        .item - clip .has-mask {
    position: absolute;
    clip: rect (10px, 190px, 190px, 10px);
    opacity: 0.5; / * 50% opacity * /
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. but when i added the code you have suggested. it will only add a opacity on the image itself. but not on the covered area of clip.